# Issue while creating 4 matplotlib subplots with different fields and colour scheme using functions

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, matplotlib, parameter-passing

I am trying to plot 4 subplots containing different fields and color schemes. For this, I have created the function **colour** taking parameters as the colour scheme and list location of the field to be plotted.
**Colour** leads to another function **field** which invokes the field to be plotted.

The code is as:

```
w1 =gas['Velocity']

w2 = gas['MagneticField']

w3=gas['Masses']

w4=gas['Density']


nPixels = [300,300]
minMax = [0, header['BoxSize']]

weights=[w1,w2,w3,w4]


def field(j):
     grid, _, _, _ = binned_statistic_2d(x, y, weights[j], 'sum', bins=nPixels, range=[minMax,minMax])



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=2, figure=fig)

extent = [0, header['BoxSize'], 0, header['BoxSize']]

def colour(c,j):
    field(j)
    plt.imshow(np.log10(grid), cmap=c,extent=extent, aspect= 1)
    plt.colorbar()
    
f1_ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0])
f1_ax1.set_title('Magnetic Field')
colour('viridis',0)

f1_ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 1])
f1_ax2.set_title('Velocity')
colour('inferno',1)

f1_ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 0])
f1_ax3.set_title('Masses')
colour('cividis',2)

f1_ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 1])
f1_ax4.set_title('Density')
colour('magma',3)
```

However, on running the code I fet the following error:

```
ipython-input-8-3f2f0683bc0b> in <module>
     11 f1_ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0])
     12 f1_ax1.set_title('Magnetic Field')
---> 13 colour('viridis',0)
     14 
     15 f1_ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 1])

<ipython-input-8-3f2f0683bc0b> in colour(c, j)
      6 def colour(c,j):
      7     field(j)
----> 8     plt.imshow(np.log10(grid), cmap=c,extent=extent, aspect= 1)
      9     plt.colorbar()
     10 

NameError: name 'grid' is not defined
```

I cant understand what is going wrong. Request any help possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Defining grid as a global variable solves the issue!

Inside `field(j)` function, write `global grid` as the first line